# VBA Getting data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am having trouble when getting data from SQL Server. Here is the code.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim blsCritical As Boolean

'----------------------------------------------
ListBox.AddItem "Initializing..."
'----------------------------------------------
Me.Repaint

'----------------------------------------------
ListBox.AddItem "Welcome"
'----------------------------------------------
Me.Repaint

'----------------------------------------------
ListBox.AddItem "Examining your access rights..."

Call ConnectSQLServer
'----------------------------------------------
Me.Repaint

ListBox.AddItem strSQL
'----------------------------------------------
ListBox.AddItem "Opening database connection..."
'----------------------------------------------
Me.Repaint

End Sub

Sub ConnectSQLServer()

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String
Dim par As ADODB.Parameter

Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

objMyConn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
objMyConn.Open

strSQL = "SELECT [currentVersion], [standardVersion] FROM [dbo].[Version]"

If currentVersion = "" Then
    MsgBox ("No currentVersion value")
ElseIf Not IsNull(currentVersion) Then
    If currentVersion < standardVersion Then
        MsgBox ("Upgrade is needed")
    ElseIf currentVersion = standardVersion Then
        MsgBox ("PASS")
    Else
    End If
Else
End If

Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

End Sub
```

I have data in SQL Server:

[image]

but I cannot get data from SQL Server. When I execute it, 'No CurrentVersion value' message pops up. I don't see any mistakes in my code. Could you help me to solve this problem?(It would be great if you can share your fixed code...)

Comment: you are missing the point of the handling a recordset... open the recordset first then get the fields from the recordset and do your stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just whipped this up for you to show you where you went wrong...  untested...

```
strSQL = "SELECT [currentVersion], [standardVersion] FROM [dbo].[Version]"    

Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

while objMyRecordset.EOF = false
currentVersion = objMyRecordset!currentVersion
objMyRecordset.MoveNext 
wend

If currentVersion = "" Then
    MsgBox ("No currentVersion value")
ElseIf Not IsNull(currentVersion) Then
    If currentVersion < standardVersion Then
        MsgBox ("Upgrade is needed")
    ElseIf currentVersion = standardVersion Then
        MsgBox ("PASS")
    Else
    End If
Else
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job.

```
Sub GetDataFromADO()

    'Declare variables'
        Set objMyconn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
        Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rc As Long

    'Open Connection'
        objMyconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SAXAM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

        objMyconn.Open

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
        Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyconn
        objMyCmd.CommandText = "select * from [Person].[BusinessEntity] "
        objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        objMyCmd.Execute

    'Open Recordset'
        Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyconn
        objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd

    'Copy Data to Excel'
        'ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
        Application.ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
        rc = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveSheet.Cells(rc + 1, 1).Select
        'Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value
        objMyconn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more idea.  Let's say you had a bunch of Select statements in a bunch of cells from A1, down to whatever, you can add sheets dynamically, and import some sample data on to each sheet, to get a sense of the data structures of multiple tables.

Assuming the following in A1:A3.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [YOUR_DB].[dbo].[YOUR_TABLE1]
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [YOUR_DB].[dbo].[YOUR_TABLE2]
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [YOUR_DB].[dbo].[YOUR_TABLE3]
```

Run the script below.

```
Sub Download_From_Multiple_Tables()

'Initializes variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long


Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'For a trusted Connection, where your user ID has permissions on the SQL Server:
cnn.Open ConnectionString:="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
"Data Source=" & "YOUR_SERVER_NAME" & ";Initial Catalog=" & "YOUR_DB_NAME" & _
";TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES"


'Opens connection to the database
'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query; this will run for 15 minutes before VBA timesout, but your database might timeout before this value
cnn.CommandTimeout = 900


Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
LRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & LRow)
    i = 2
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

        LPosition = InStrRev(rCell.Value, "[dbo]") + 5

        ' Name the newly added worksheet, based on the cell value
        Name = Mid(rCell.Value, LPosition + 1, 99)

        ' Remove [] characters, as these are not permitted in tab names
        Name = Replace(Name, "[", "")
        Name = Replace(Name, "]", "")

        SheetName = Left(Name, 31)

        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = SheetName
        Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
        StrQuery = rCell.Value
            'Performs the actual query
            rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
            'Dumps all the results from the StrQuery into cell A2 of the first sheet in the active workbook


            ' Dump field names to the worksheet
            For intFieldIndex = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(1, intFieldIndex + 1).Value = rst.Fields(intFieldIndex).Name
            Next intFieldIndex

             ' Dump the records to the worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst
            ' Sheets(i).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

            i = i + 1
            rst.Close
    Next rCell

End Sub
```